# How can I lapply to sub element of list within a list

Tags: r, apply, lapply

Suppose I have a **list nested within a list** and I have some function which only works on vectors (like str_replace from the stringr package). The **function should do its work on every element** which actually entails information, ...

**Question 1:** Is there a specific solution to my problem? 
**Question 2:** Is there a general solution?

There should be a solution using loops, but that is all but elegant and probably very slow - efficiency does play a role here.

Let's have an **example**:

```
# let's start easy:
test1 <- list(c("a","d"),c("b","d"),c("c","d"))

# does not work:
str_replace(test1,"d","changed")

# but this does:
lapply(test1,str_replace,"d","changed")

# but what now ?
test2 <- list(c(list("a"),"d"),c("b","d"),c("c","d"))

# does not work! :-(
lapply(test2,str_replace,"d","changed")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `unlist`/`relist`:

```
library(stringr)
test <- list(c(list("a"),"d"),c("b","d"),c("c","d"))
test2 <- unlist(test)
test2 <- str_replace(test2,"d","changed")
relist(test2,test)

[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "a"

[[1]][[2]]
[1] "changed"


[[2]]
[1] "b"       "changed"

[[3]]
[1] "c"       "changed"
```

I believe this is pretty efficient, but have not tested.

Comment: Although, more steps are involved here then in Matthew Lundberg's answer this solution is 3 times faster.

Comment: This solution has a flaw though. If the list entails holes (NULL values in parts of the list) like in: `list(c(list("a"),"d"),c("b","d"),c("c","d"),c(NULL),c("a","d"))` , it will not work. See Matthew Lundberg's approach for a robust solution.

Comment: I would not consider that a flaw, since you did not state that the list can contain empty lists (and I don't see a good reason why it should). However, it's always necessary to balance performance vs robustness carefully.

Comment: Sure, I did not state that in the question - no offence. But some would mind if it is robust to such or not (I actually do for my stuff) . Its just an additional information.

Answer (score 8):

Here is how to use rapply for this.  Note the position of the ... in the definition of rapply - this comes after `dflt` and `how`.  For this reason, we name the arguments to str_replace:

```
rapply(test,str_replace,pattern="d",replacement="changed",how='replace')

[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "a"

[[1]][[2]]
[1] "changed"


[[2]]
[1] "b"       "changed"

[[3]]
[1] "c"       "changed"
```

Comment: Although, more steps are involved in Roland's solution it seems to be more efficient.

Comment: This solution also copes consistantly with holes in parts of the list (NULL) like in: `list(c(list("a"),"d"),c("b","d"),c("c","d"),c(NULL),c("a","d"))`

Answer (score 2):

`rapply` recursively applies a function to each list element. You might have to experiment with the parameter `how` to get the right output, but it should give you what you need.

`rapply` documentation is [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/rapply.html).